# Using mapping char filter when index created using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to apply 'mapping character filter'(for mapping dots as spaces) in elasticsearch but unable to find the file where the configuration can be done. The indexes in my elasticsearch instance are being created by logstash using a template which also adds the .raw fields. How do I configure elasticsearch for my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash ships with an index template for logstash-* indexes that, as you've noted, adds the .raw fields. The file is named elasticsearch-template.json and is installed as /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json if you install the Debian package.

Don't edit it directly, but you make a copy of it and set the [`template` field for the elasticsearch output](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch#template) to point to your copy. Optionally, set [`manage_template`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch#manage_template) to false if you want to manage the templates yourself instead of letting Logstash do it for you.